# ListView's item - move on touch

Tags: android, android-view, drag

I want to move each items of my `listview` by drag.
I set OnTouch for `listview` and drag and drop items by set left and right margin.
This is my procedure:

```
private void setLastViewDistance(float distanceX, View lastView) {
    if (lastView.getLayoutParams().getClass() == AbsListView.LayoutParams.class)
        lastView = ((ViewGroup) lastView).getChildAt(0);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) lastView.getLayoutParams();
    lp.leftMargin = (int) distanceX;
    lp.rightMargin = -(int) distanceX;
    lastView.setLayoutParams(lp);
    lastView.postInvalidate();
}
```

But this code is slow motion in phone device.
is any idea like setLeft(not work) setRight(not work) or...?
thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this question is nearly the same as yours: [android drag view smooth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8535599/android-drag-view-smooth)

Drag and drop in listview is somehow complicated... But there's a library for that (https://github.com/bauerca/drag-sort-listview) or you can read this drag and drop tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidDragAndDrop/article.html