# SurfaceViewRenderer view unable to drag around screen Android WebRTC

Tags: android, kotlin, webrtc, surfaceview, drag

In my application I have integrated the WebRTC protocol so I can make a video call with participants. In order to show my local camera stream, I use a `SurfaceViewRenderer` inherited from this package `org.webrtc.SurfaceViewRenderer`

However I want to be able to drag the view around in the screen. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: totally nothing...i have posted in Google Conversation but nothing. I need this

Comment: Have you tried to use the drag & drop guide? ignore the fact this is SurfaceViewRenderer it is just another view. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop

Comment: @Arjun finally i did this. But i extended a FrameLayout instead of ImageView, that has a SurfaceViewRenderer as a child

https://stackoverflow.com/a/63269223/5371749